# Drupal VIEWS API?

Tags: views

I know there is the VIEWS API -- but what I am looking for is a method I can call passing the view by machine name and receive the raw PHP array (not rendered) -- where is the obvious function? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be [`views_get_view_result`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_get_view_result/7) which takes the view machine name and display id as arguments and returns the response as an array containing the result object

Comment: Not sure how I missed that function :s I literally went through each of the function at least twice :)